# Fetch attribute values of image tag from different webpage in scala js

Tags: javascript, scala.js

I have two html pages : main.html and referrer.html . On referrer.html page I have an image tag with custom attributes that I added using :

```
data-*
```

like :

```
data-name="abc"
data-roll="12"
data-marks="78"
```

and so on.
When I click on this image, it redirects me to main.html. I am trying to fetch data from this web page and display it on main.html. I am using,

```
org.scalajs.dom.document.referrer
```

to refer to referrer.html page from main.html. But it is not working. And moreover how can I fetch the above attributes values ? I am using scala js.

Comment: Could you give more details on what you have tried so far? How does the redirect work? How did you use `referrer`? What does "it is not working" mean? As it stands, you question is very vague, and it is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @sjrd I'm using `org.scala.dom` document to refer to the web page I am working on, which is main.html. I used `val ref=org.scalajs.dom.document.referrer` to get the url of the referrer web page i.e. referrer.html. 
I've linked both pages such that when a user click on the image in referrer.html, it redirects him to main.html and the `ref` field produces the url of referrer.html as its output. But the `ref` is producing null instead of the url of referrer.

Comment: Further, I've added some attributes in the html code of the image in referrer.html using `data-*` where * represents custom attribute name. How can I fetch their value from main.html ?

Comment: `referrer` can't be used that way -- see [the documentation page for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) for more information, but basically it doesn't work when you've just clicked through.  (Indeed, I don't think I've ever found a practical use for `referrer`.)

Comment: Really, it's impossible to do this the way you're trying to -- by the time you're on main.html, you've already lost referrer.html.  Instead, you need to intercept the click on referrer.html, do something like capture and encode the data parameters there, before navigating to main.html, and pass them along as URL parameters or something like that.

Comment: okay ! Thank you. @JustinduCoeur